# Spyder in Windows 10: Python console not printing properly

Tags: python, spyder

I have been trying to use Spyder 3.0.2 (came with Anaconda) on a Windows 10 machine. I can not get the displaying of variable in the Python console to work properly. Here is an example of what happens when I try to print:

```
>>> a=5
>>> a
5>> >

>>> a=0.5
>>> a
0.>> >5
```

I also have to hit enter after submitting the command to get the prompt back.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is a known problem and we're working to fix it. Unfortunately, we are still trying to find the source of the problem.

*Note*: This only happens on Windows. Other platforms are not affected by this problem.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for replying! Do you have any workarounds for the time being? Thanks again!

Comment: Nop, sorry. Just recommend you to use the IPython console instead because the Python console is going to be removed in the future.